# Magento Upgrade : 2.0.2 to 2.1.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade

After upgrade magento 2.0.2 to 2.1.2 through composer i get following error :

```
Autoload error: 'magento/framework' component already exists
```

How to solve this error?

Without that i can't access front end and back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved above error by clear following directories :

> **{magento root}** \app\design\frontend\Magento
>
> **{magento root}** \app\code\Magento
>
> **{magento root}** \lib\internal\Magento\Framework